# VBA: Consolidation function on array reference (mix of text & number)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to consolidate a range of cells from multiple spreadsheets which I know I can handle it with "Consolidate" function in excel.

I have a set of cells formulated with texts and number by concatenating them.

(e.g, = "E by " & 2)

I want to ultimately consolidate only the last digit of the cell but over the whole range from all other spreadsheets. They share same location within a same tab name with same formula.

If I use standard consolidate function it returns zero as the array cannot recognize only digits.

Is there any way I could use consolidate function VBA such that I can only consolidate the digit number only (last digit in this case)?

Codes that I have are as below.

Thank you for the help.

```
        If Cell <> "" Then
            i = i + 1
            ReDim Preserve WeeklyErrorArray(1 To i)
WeeklyErrorArray(i) = Replace(Replace("'[" & Filename & " (" & Locname & ") " & "CY20CONSOL.xlsm]63 Wk Hours'!R7C4:R90C4", "/", " "), "'", "")
Next
Counter = 0
Selection.Consolidate Sources:=(WeeklyErrorArray(counter + 1)), Function:=xlSum, TopRow:=False, LeftColumn:=False, CreateLinks:=False
```

Comment: Code runs but returns empty cells instead of zeros

Comment: 'ReDim Preserve` is very slow when the count gets high.. my hack is to `count` the range first then `declare` your array with the exact variables..